# Why might building a vdproj file in visual studio try to trigger a restore of my computer?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vdproj

I have a strange build bug on my machine where triggering a Build on a vdproj fires up a dialog which says:

Please wait while Windows configures Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Isolated).

This runs for a bit and then errors with:

One or more of the files required to restore your computer to its previous state could not be found. Restoration will not be possible.

The project was compiling correctly last week and no changes have been made to the deployment project (a few bug fixes have been made to the code that it's packaging up, but rolling these back does not fix the error).

Since the code is the same, I'm assuming something on the local machine has changed, but I'm not sure how to go about diagnosing the issue. Have there been recent changes in Windows that might have broken Visual Studio 2015? How can I find out what the underlying problem is?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell is a separate application which doesn't support .vdproj files and was taking over the build (Although I'm not sure why this was trying to build instead of Visual Studio Professional where I triggered the build).

Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell application was installed last week (not sure if this was by another user or by Microsoft updates).

Uninstalling Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell from my machine has fixed this build error.